# Vue Event listener on mouse hold

Tags: vue.js

How can you set a boolean to true when the mouse click is held down, and false when you release the click? On Vue I am using  `v-on:mousedown="hold = !hold"` But this toggles the boolean instead of having the user hold the click down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the events `mousedown` and `mouseup`. Try something like this:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div :style="{ 'background-color': color }">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
    </div>
    <button @mousedown="color = 'orange'" @mouseup="color = 'green'" >Click here</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data: () => ({
    color: 'yellow',
  }),
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use both `mousedown` and `mouseup` events.

```
<div
  v-on:mousedown="hold = true"
  v-on:mouseup="hold = false"
>{{hold}}</div>
```